# How do I access the request object in a form_class, django, CBV

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to pass the data from the request to my form.
Currently, that is resulting in an error:

> BaseModelForm.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'

My view:

```
class TaskCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
   model = Task
   template_name = "tasks/task_form.html"
   form_class = DateInputForm
```

My view (get_form_kwargs function):

```
    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        form_kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return form_kwargs
```

Init from my form :

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        self.fields['tags'].queryset = Tag.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
```

*I know that I can find the user's ID in my request*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
(1) My view (get_form_kwargs function):

```
    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        form_kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return form_kwargs
```

(2) Init from my form:

```
    def __init__(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['tags'].queryset = Tag.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
```